# How I hide empty Velocity variable names?

Tags: java, templates, struts, velocity

I am using Struts + Velocity in a Java application, but after I submit a form, the confirmation page (Velocity template) shows the variable names instead an empty label, like the Age in following example:

> **Name**: Fernando
>
> **Age**: {person.age}
>
> **Sex**: Male

I would like to know how to hide it!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can mark variables as "[silent](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation)" like this:

```
$!variable
```

If $variable is null, nothing will be rendered. If it is not null, its value will render as it normally would.

Answer (score 14):

You will also need to be sure and use the proper syntax.  Your example is missing the dollar before the variable.  It should be $!{person.age}, not just {person.age}.

Comment: Not to be funny but isn't your syntax also incorrect? You don't use curly brackets around a velocity variable do you?

Comment: Yes, i do. They are optional, though. :) We call it "formal syntax".

Comment: Oh, well .. I better check that out then!

Comment: More info on Formal Reference Notation is avalable [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation).